# c++ : parse file to find precise line

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm a beginner I c++ so I don't really know if a function like I search already exists. I want a function that parse a file to find a line that begin by a precise string, and return it.

For example, If I have a file like that :

```
test  4645
foo   erf   rfr 564
bar   I like train
sponge bob
```

I would like to do something like

```
std::string line = Func("/my/path/file", "bar");
std::cout << line << std::endl; // display bar    I like train
```

Comment: You must create this code yourself, as nothing exactly similar already exists. Start by reading the file line by line (maybe use std::getline?). Take each line in turn, and see if the beginning of the line == bar (various comparison functions available, such as _wcsicmp, being careful when line is short or 0 length), finally, return the remainder of the line (substr).

Comment: You can read each line to a `string` and use `substr()` to check if contains `"bar"` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function does not exist, but all building blocks are ready in C++ standard library. Something like

```
std::string Func(const std::string& file, const std::string& prefix)
{
    std::ifstream input(file);
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line))
        if (line.find(prefix) == 0)
            return line;
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a stream for a prefix in each line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream in(
        "test  4645\n"
        "foo   erf   rfr 564\n"
        "bar   I like train\n"
        "sponge bob\n");

    std::string prefix = "bar";

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(in, line)) {
        if(line.compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Result: " <<  line << '\n';
            return 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "No result\n";
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should read file line by line the try to find specific word in the line 
try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string find_in_line (const string& fileName, const string& searchWord)
{
string STRING;
ifstream infile;
infile.open (fileName);

while(!infile.eof()) // To get you all the lines.
{
    getline(infile,STRING); // Saves the line in STRING.
    if (STRING.find(searchWord) != std::string::npos){        
    {
        // YOU GOT THE LINE CONTAINING "bar"
        infile.close();            
        return STRING;
    }

}
infile.close();
}
```

i think this should work ...

Comment: Also check input stream for `fail()` - if something goes wrong you won't even reach EOF.

Comment: this is not complete code for doing the search , this is the approach of what should be done.